# Multiple instance of GoogleApiClient

Tags: android, google-plus, google-fit

**Context**

When my app is launched for the first time, it asks the user to connect to *Google Fit* and in the next step (another activity), he has the possibility to connect to *Google Plus*.

When I accepted to connect to both APIs, once in my app, I have the possibility to disconnect from *Fit* or *Plus*, but, I don't know why, it is impossible to disconnect from *Fit* when the *Plus* client is connected and if I disconnect from *Plus*, it works well, but the *Fit* client gets also disconnected.

When the app is launched, if I decide to connect only to *Fit* and not *Plus*, it works as expected, I mean I can disconnect correctly from *Fit*.

**Question**

I thought that it was possible to have multiple instances of `GoogleApiClient`, but I have the impression that both clients are "connected".

Is there a kind of hierarchy between the API clients?

**Edit**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    /**
     * Create the fitness client - this is mandatory to use the app
     */
    buildFitnessClient();

    /**
     * Get the result of Google Plus connection
     */
    // If skip button is clicked, the user does not want to connect to G+
    Boolean isSkipClicked = getSharedPreferences("ISSKIPCLICKED", MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("isSkipClicked", false);
    if(isSkipClicked){
        // The user has the possibility to connect to G+ through the menu
    }
    // else, the user is connected to G+, rebuilt the client
    else{
        buildPlusClient();
        mPlusClient.connect();
    }
}
```

The **buildFitnessClient()** :

```
private void buildFitnessClient() {
    // Create the Google API Client
    mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API)
            .addApi(Fitness.RECORDING_API)
            .addApi(Fitness.CONFIG_API)
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_LOCATION_READ_WRITE))
            .addScope(new Scope((Scopes.FITNESS_NUTRITION_READ_WRITE)))
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_BODY_READ_WRITE))
            .addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
                                            Log.i(TAG, "Connected to Fitness API!!!");
                                            // Now you can make calls to the Fitness APIs.
                                            // Put application specific code here.

                                            mClient.connect();
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                                            // If your connection to the sensor gets lost at some point,
                                            // you'll be able to determine the reason and react to it here.
                                            if (i == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_NETWORK_LOST) {
                                                Log.i(TAG, "Connection lost.  Cause: Network Lost.");
                                            } else if (i == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_SERVICE_DISCONNECTED) {
                                                Log.i(TAG, "Connection lost.  Reason: Service Disconnected");
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
            )
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                                               // Called whenever the API client fails to connect.
                                               @Override
                                               public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
                                                   Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed. Cause: " + result.toString());
                                                   if (!result.hasResolution()) {
                                                       // Show the localized error dialog
                                                       GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(),
                                                               Main2Activity.this, 0).show();
                                                       return;
                                                   }
                                                   // The failure has a resolution. Resolve it.
                                                   // Called typically when the app is not yet authorized, and an
                                                   // authorization dialog is displayed to the user.
                                                   if (!authInProgress) {
                                                       try {
                                                           Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to resolve failed connection");
                                                           authInProgress = true;
                                                           result.startResolutionForResult(Main2Activity.this, REQUEST_OAUTH);
                                                       } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                                                           Log.e(TAG, "Exception while starting resolution activity", e);
                                                       }
                                                   }
                                               }
                                           }
            )
            .build();
}
```

The **buildPlusClient** method:

```
public void buildPlusClient(){
    /**
     * Handle the connection to Google Plus client
     */

    // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
    // profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .requestProfile()
            .build();

    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener unresolvedConnectionFailedListener = new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
        }
    };

    // Build a GoogleApiClient with access to the Google Sign-In API and the
    // options specified by gso.
    mPlusClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, unresolvedConnectionFailedListener /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
}
```

Below, methods to disconnect from Gplus and/or Gfit:

```
private void signOutFit(){
            if(mClient.isConnected()){
                Fitness.ConfigApi.disableFit(mClient)
                        .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResult(Status status) {
                                if (status.isSuccess()) {
                                    //Log.d(TAG, "Disconnect success");
                                    Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this,"Disconnected from Google Fit",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this,"Impossible to disconnect from Fit",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
}

private void signOutPlus(){
    if(mPlusClient.isConnected()){
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mPlusClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {
                        if(status.isSuccess()){
                            Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "Disconnect from Google Plus", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "Impossible to disconnect from Google Plus", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }        
}
```

Comment: maybe you'll need to post some of your code. Especially the parts that are related to the "re"use of the GoogleApiClient

Comment: Is it the code pasted identical to your app? You are calling mClient.connect()  in onConnected?

Comment: Also, "if I disconnect from Plus, it works well, but the Fit client gets also disconnected." - you are calling  Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut, which basically signs the user out. Sign-in state is global to your application including Fitness / GoogleSignIn. You explicitly signs the user out, so Fitness can no longer connect() successfully. (Yup, it's a little tricky, for Fitness, you will need to complete the sign in flow to get into CONNECTED state; for GoogleSignInApi, since it helps you to establish sign-in state, so itself doesn't require a signed-in session.)

Comment: Yes, the code I pasted here is the same as in my app. Ok, I understand the point concerning the signing out. But concerning the signing in...it is not enough clear for me :)